# How do I get the total price from my carList?

Tags: java, arraylist, js-test-driver

I am creating a class called `Car` with a method called `TotalPrice` which will take an array of `Car`s and calculate the total for the list. I have implemented a client method `totalPrice`, which accepts a list (`ArrayUnsortedList carList`) of cars and returns an integer equal to the total cost of the cars on the list.

I am stuck on writing the test driver so that I can test my actual `Car` class program.

Here's my code for the `Car` class:

```
public class Car
{
   int year;
   String make;
   String model;
   int price;

   public Car(int year, String make, String model, int price) {
      this.year = year;
      this.make = make;
      this.model = model;
      this.price = price;      
   }

   public int getYear() {
      return this.year;
   }

   public String getMake() {
      return make;
   }

   public String getModel() {
      return model;
   }

   public int getPrice() {
      return this.price;
   }

   public static int totalPrice(ArrayUnsortedList carList) {
      int totalPrice = 0;
      for(int i=carList.size(); i>0; i--)
      {

         totalPrice += ((Car)carList.getNext()).getPrice();
      }
      return totalPrice;
   }      
}
```

Here's my test drive class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CarList{

   public static void main (String [] args) {

      ArrayUnsortedList<Car> carList = new ArrayUnsortedList<Car>();  
      Car car1, car2;

      car1 = new Car(2016, "BMW", "M4", 65700);
      carList.add(car1);    
      car1 = new Car(2016, "Mercedes-Benz", "C300", 38950);
      carList.add(car1);    
      car2 = new Car(2016, "Lexus", "GS F", 84440);
      carList.add(car2);

      System.out.println(Car.totalPrice(carList));

   }   

}
```

UPDATE********

*I have to use ArrayUnsortedList that is given.*

Here are the rest of the codes: [GITHUB](https://gist.github.com/76342ck/31cf07f5742b890af0b5)

**UPDATE**
*Now I am getting the wrong totalPrice?*

65700 + 38950 + 84440 = 189090

But I get 253320???

```
 ----jGRASP exec: java CarList

253320

 ----jGRASP: operation complete.
```

Comment: `Car.totalPrice(carList)`?

Comment: @skypjack I cannot use that because it is incompatible with my ArrayUnsortedList

Comment: Well, build an `ArrayUnsortedList` from the other list or define a constructor that accepts a generic list, then use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the code of the `totalPrice` function itself, I would use `ArrayUnsortedList.size()` and `ArrayUnsortedList.getNext()` to browse the list content. This list api is terrible (intentionally, I suppose) and it's understandable you had a little difficulties here. Learn to quickly browse a Java class, looking only at the function headers to determine which function can be useful.

```
int totalPrice = 0;
for(int i=carList.size(); i>0; i--)
{
  totalPrice += carList.getNext().getPrice();
}
return totalPrice;
```

You will notice I do not reference `i` inside the loop ; that's because there is no method of `ArrayUnsortedList` that expects an index. So I just rely on `i` to make sure I make the good number of calls to `ArrayUnsortedList.getNext()`.

On other topics,

- I don't think it's the job of the Car class to sum the price of cars. `totalPrice` should imo be implemented as a function on the `ArrayUnsortedList` or simply executed as is in your test class.
- I think tests in Java environment should be run with JUnit. This might be a topic you'll soon encounter, but if you've already worked with JUnit then your test runner should use it.

Comment: If i change it to what you have posted, i get an error `Car.java:35: error: cannot find symbol`

Comment: It looks like your function or code block currently accepts untyped ArrayUnsortedList. You should either change the signature to only accept `ArrayUnsortedList<Car>`, so the `carList.getNext()` naturally returns a `Car` on which you can call `.getPrice()`, or use a cast in the loop : `((Car)carList.getNext()).getPrice()`

Comment: If you look at the error you pasted in your question, you can see Java's trying to find a function `getPrice()` on the class `Object`, while it should be looking for it on the class `Car`

Answer (score 0):

In your main method, you can add cars to the given datatype (ArrayUnsortedList) itself. Then you can directly pass it to your static method.

Another alternative is to define a constructor for the ArrayUnsortedList to take in an ArrayList, and create its own instance with appropriate elements.